# Add Datetime Stamp to SAS 9.1.3 Filename?

Tags: datetime, sas, filenames

I'll start by saying I have very little experience with SAS.  I'm working with SAS 9.1.3 in Windows.  I have no choice in the matter.

I need to name  SAS Transport (XPT) file with the format "CR845_CLIN2001_LB_Date_Time.xpt". Currently I have a script that names it with just the date (sysdate9).

The lines of code that use the date are as follows - these are the lines that I think need to be changed - they are not all in a block:

```
libname XPORTOUT xport "\\ACMSHARES2\CLNTRIAL\DataMgt\C1845\DataTransfer\Data\Sent\SAS\CR845_CLIN2001_LB_&sysdate9..xpt";

data LabData.&fileBaseName._&sysdate9 (COMPRESS=YES);

data LB.LB; 
    set LabData.&fileBaseName._&sysdate9; 
run;

proc contents data = LabData.&fileBaseName._&sysdate9 varnum;
run;
```

I've tried a couple of things but SAS rejects colons in the time. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not SAS that rejects the colons. It's Windows. Colons are invalid in file names; on Windows it's a drive separator (as in `C:`, `D:`, etc.). Regardless of the tool, you cannot use invalid characters in filenames. Replace them with a valid character, or format them as `CCYYMMDD HHMMSS` or `CCYY-MM-DD HHMMSS` instead.

Comment: Your point is taken, however the problem is that I don't know how to format datetimes in SAS. I barely know SAS at all and I don't think anyone else here does either, this just got dropped in my lap. I think the guy who I replaced was their SAS programmer, or at least knew more about it than I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I cobbled together a truly awful solution. It works, but it's ugly as sin. I added this mess:

```
%let cyear=%sysfunc(putn("&sysdate9"d, year4.));
%let cmon =%SUBSTR(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%sysevalf(%SYSFUNC(TODAY())),DATE9.)),3,3);
%let cday =%SUBSTR(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%sysevalf(%SYSFUNC(TODAY())),DATE9.)),1,2);
%let chour=%SUBSTR(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%sysevalf(%SYSFUNC(TIME())),TIME5.)),1,2);
%let cmin=%SUBSTR(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%sysevalf(%SYSFUNC(TIME())),TIME5.)),4,2);
```

and then put this in place of "sysdate9" in the lines of code shown in my original question:

```
&cyear&cmon&cday._&chour&cmin
```

It works, but I hate it. Improvements welcome!

Comment: If you want YYYYMMDD, then `%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8.)` will get you that.  So `%sysfunc(Today(),yymmddn8.)_&chour.&cmin.` for example.

Comment: I ended up refining it to this:
    `%let dt=%sysfunc(date(),yymmddn8);  
    %let dt=&dt._%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(time(),time5),:));  
  
    data LabData.&fileBaseName._&dt (COMPRESS=YES);`  

Etc.

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill for your purpose, but others may find this useful.  In SAS you can create your own datetime formats when you find the existing ones lacking.

A good whitepaper [can be found here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/026-2007.pdf).

Here is an example that would create the format you are trying to achieve:

```
proc format;
  picture myfmt low-high = '%Y%0m%0d_%0H%0M' (datatype = datetime) ;
run ;
```

Example usage:

```
%put %sysfunc(datetime(), myfmt.);
```

Gives:

```
20150819_1304
```

If you want to add seconds, the token for it is: `%0S`.

Answer (score 1):

Colons are disallowed in Windows filenames.  Use a better format, such as my personal preference, [b8601dt](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169749.htm):

```
proc export data=sashelp.class 
            outfile="c:\temp\class_%sysfunc(datetime(),B8601DT15.).csv" 
            dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

However, for 9.1.3, B8601DT (and the other IEEE date formats) isn't supported, since that's around fifteen years old... you'd have to come up with another, more piecemeal solution.

My preference here would be to represent the time in *seconds*, which would make the filename still able to be unique (and sort properly).  Split date and time.  I assume here your use of `&sysdate9` is acceptable (this is the date SAS *starts*, not the date of today, but if this is a batch job it'll be fine); but still I use `%today()` over `&systime` as it's easier to get it formatted quickly.

Comment: b8601dt was one of the things I tried. I got a "format not found" error when I tried to run the SAS program.

Comment: I'm using SAS 9.1, maybe that's the reason.  That's what we have in the office, I have no control over that.

Comment: Yeah, that's apparently correct - must've been added in 9.2  Apologies, 9.1.3 is old enough it's not really well supported any more (and your office should upgrade!)

Comment: There's more than one thing they need to upgrade here, but it's probably not happening before I need to generate this Transport file!

Comment: When your version is old enough to be in high school, it's probably time to upgrade... ;)

Comment: Some of the software in this place is old enough to vote.

Comment: Try `nd8601dt15.` - I think this does what you want in 9.1.3.

Comment: @user667489 That is an informat, not a format, from my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a macro variable with the suffix you want. I would recommend using format of YYYYMMDD_HHMM as it will sort properly. Then use the new macro variable in place of &SYSDATE9 when generating the name of the XPORT file.

```
%let dt=%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8)_%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(time(),time5),:));
libname XPORTOUT xport "\\....\CR845_CLIN2001_LB_&dt..xpt";
```

If you want to include seconds then use TIME8 instead of TIME5 format.

Answer (score 0):

Since the colons are the issue, you could remove them using the compress function which I believe did exist in SAS 9.1.3.  Not pretty, but quick and effective.

```
%let today=%sysfunc(datetime(), datetime21.);
%let today=%sysfunc(compress(&today, :));
%put &today;
```

> 19AUG2015141413

And another way to get the T in there

```
data _null_;
date=put(datetime(), datetime21. -l);
substr(date, 10, 1)="T";
date=compress(date, ":");
call symputx('date_value', date);
run;

%put &date_value;
```

> 19AUG2015T141801